# Express.js / Node.js: Order of Routes important and where to put next()?

Tags: node.js, express

I have my routes and path set up like this:

```
var path1        = express.Router()
  , path2        = express.Router()
  // .. more modules, e.g. express-jwt ..

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

  var path1Func = function(req, res) {

  return MODEL.findById(req.params.id, function(err, model) {

      if(!model) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return res.send({ status: '404 Not found' });
      }

      if(!err) {
        return res.send({ status: 'OK', model:model });
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        return res.send({ status: '500 Server error' });
      }
    });
  };

  // .. other functions which essentially look like above path1Func ..

  path1.get('/subPath',            path1Func             );
  path2.get('/otherSubPath',            path2Func             );
  path2.post('/entirelyOtherSubPath',           otherPath2Func        );

  app.use('/path1', path1);
  app.use('/path2', path2);

  app.use('/grid', expressJwt({secret: secret}));  // Protect Paths
}
```

Now, Depending on ordering of my HTTP requests, POST, GET, etc, they get executed or returning a 404 not found, meaning that express does not resolve requests to some requests, depending of ordering of `path1.get`, `path2.get`, `path2.post`.

[image: express1Order]
[image: express2Order]

*Above Images depict the 404 I am seeing, depending on the order of the route declarations in my routes.js file. When I reshuffle my order, the 404 is gone and I am served my wanted output*

This is why I want to employ next() to help me with that - keeping in mind I am using plenty of `app.use` to complicate matters. I did not manage to do this on my own so far. I am still not clear what next() exactly is and how to use it in above example to make my router work in every route. I did not put my other routes here to save space, but my API is already quite big and will grow even more.

What would be an approach here to make my app serve content, no matter what order my `POST` and `GET` requests are ordered?

Comment: It's hard for us to help without some context as to what your routes under `...other functions...` are for, as well as what module the other code is for.

Comment: sorry I made an error abstracting the code for SO. let me correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that particular request you've shown gets a 404 is because you don't have a route pattern that matches.

You're requesting `/grid/dates/:val` but you only have a `/grid` route. Even if you change `/grid` to `/grid/dates/:val`, you still aren't responding to the request because all `expressJwt()` does is validate the request and then passes execution to the next handler. So with that in mind, you might try something like:

```
app.use('/grid/dates/:val',
        expressJwt({secret: secret}),
        function(req, res) {
  res.send(200, 'hello world!');
});
```

Comment: sorry had confusing code, now it is corrected (only the screenshots differ). The route mapping is fine, believe me.

Comment: Tried your recommendation, that construct with expressJwt and a function after it does not work on my side.. prolly syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using your `Routers` wrong

```
path1.get('/path1',            path1Func             );
path2.get('/path2',            path2Func             );
path2.post('/path2',           otherPath2Func        );

app.use('/path1', path1);
app.use('/path2', path2);
```

This will use the routes `/path1/path1` and `/path2/path2`
When what you want is:

```
path1.get('/',            path1Func             );
path2.get('/',            path2Func             );
path2.post('/',           otherPath2Func        );

app.use('/path1', path1);
app.use('/path2', path2);
```

Although I'm not sure how `expressJwt` is.

I don't see anywhere you would need to use `next` since all of the route path's look unique.
You may need to provide more information if this isn't your issue.

Comment: Sorry my fault in above example, now the example code should be good. I am reading http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use so maybe that will help me. Thanks for your suggestion, although it did not help.

Comment: Sorry I still see no where you would need to use `next`. You might want to put some `console.log`s in your routes to see if it's ever hitting the route. Could be a completely different issue.

Comment: Ok I will post here when I found the solution. This also helps: http://webapplog.com/intro-to-express-js-parameters-error-handling-and-other-middleware/

Comment: Ended up not using next() until I understand it better.

Comment: There's also an APress Book coming out in November "Pro Express.js", which I look forward to.